# Old Hammer Horror 1960's early 70's - Mummy-like stone creature

Tags: identify-this-movie, black-and-white

I'm looking for a movie that was Black and white and I saw it about 1969 may be 1970 at an walk in outdoor movie theatre in Dampier Australia. I think the story was set in maybe Egypt/South America or maybe Mexico ( unsure ) and a mummy like creature was found but not in bandages it was like it was made of stone.

The creature had no real face features. Put in a crate it was transported in the back of a truck to a tomb/crypt or maybe museum room to be studied and as it was it came to life.

It broke through the truck rear window and strangled the driver. Finally it was in the Tomb/crypt or maybe museum and a lady was sketching it and I think she was wearing a brooch or necklace belonging to the Mummy/Creature. But as she drew on her pad it slowly changed/moved.

The lady thought she was overtired and kept flipping over pages to re-sketch finally realizing it was alive she faints. The creature grabbed her and carried her over land and walked into the sea and it started to dissolve and died.

The archaeologist Hubby/boyfriend then raced in and saved her from drowning.

That is all I can remember as it was a real B grader and was the first feature shown before main movie.

Comment: Perfect ! Yes that is the movie AWESOME !!! Wow just seeing that clip bought it all back. Thanks Tohood87.

Comment: Glad that was the one and happy to help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your're looking for the 1958 film **[Curse of the Faceless Man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0051507/)**

[image]

The story is about a gladiator who is discovered at Pompeii. The stone like features would be down to the ash from the volcano eruption of Mount Vesuvius.

In the trailer below you can see the scene where the driver is strangled. A lady does sit to sketch the body at one point and think she is attacked shortly after. Also at the end of the movie the faceless man walks into the sea carrying a women and begins to dissolve.

Here is the trailer: